# Mocking local method variables with mockito / powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

I have a method which takes in a string as a parameter.

However locally the method creates and uses a List and an instance of SingleColumnRowMapper.

Is there anyway using mockito/powermock once instances of these objects have been created/mocked in the unit test to place them as local variables into the method to be tested.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SampleClass classInstance = Mockito.mock(SampleClass.class);
```

The above code mocks the instance creation of a class. If you want to create any instance, create it similarly and supply it to your method.

Comment: Thanks... but if the method only takes in a String as a parameter how would I supply the mocked instances of List and SingleColumnRowMapper to the method? (Assuming this can be done :) )

Comment: Can you provide the code which creates and uses instances of List and SingleColumnRowMapper?

Comment: I believe you want to mock the constructors. Please see this link -> https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Comment: Yes this looks interesting. Thank you for your time